# How to update PHP on USBWebserver v8.6

Tags: php, superuser

Im running USBWebserver v8.6 on a USB drive on a windows 10 machine, I need to update PHP to run Mautic and it requires PHP version 5.6.19 while my USB server has PHP Version 5.4.17. I tried to download windows version and extract it to the PHP folder on the drive and did a restart on the web server but that did not work.

I don't know how to update the PHP please help.

Comment: This is a better question for [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 2):

Did you change the httpd.conf file in the Settings folder?

Almost at the end of that file there are these lines:

```
# For PHP 5 do something like this:
LoadModule php5_module "{path}/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "{path}/php"
```

Change these values according the PHP installation you want. Let me know if this works for you. I got this information from the documentation on how to install PHP.